# VB code crashes only on one machine with (OS WIN 2008 R2) and runs successfully on all other machine, After dubugging what i found out is below

Tags: listbox, vb6, windows-server-2008-r2

Following is the code for your reference... I have a browse button when I click on this I set the listbox content After I added traces on this machine I found that it crashes when `Me.csplStyles.ListIndex = p` line gets executed

```
   Private Sub cmdLineStyle_Click()
         Dim f As New frmChartElementStyles
         f.Style = LineStyle // here it perfectly returns index, 
   End Sub
    
   //Following function returns index successfully
   Private Property Get LineStyle() As Long
      Dim p As Object
      If Not Me.lvColumnsForProperties.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
         Set p = m_colColumns(Me.lvColumnsForProperties.SelectedItem.key)
         LineStyle = p.LineStyle
      End If
   End Property

   Public Property Let Style(ByVal p As Long)
       **Me.csplStyles.ListIndex = p // Here it crashes**
   End Property
```

Let me tell you that this code runs fine on all the machines. There is only one machine where I face this problem.

Comment: Crashes with a runtime error (if so what) or a fatal exit?

Comment: @AlexK. Its a Fatal exit without any error message and with no entry in windows event viewer

Comment: What is `csplStyles`?  Weird name for a ListBox *or* a ListView.  Also there is no need to hyperqualify control names using `Me.` they are in the current namespace already.

Comment: What is the exact error when it "crashes"?

Comment: @Bob77 is a third party UI control.